# How to pass data between main.js and directory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, electron

i need to know how to pass data between main and directory.

what I wanna do is to active the directive automaticly when main.js start on load.

directive code:

```
    angular.module('dmv.shared.components').
    directive('doImportPackage', ['Package', function (Package) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                onStart: '<',
                onFinish: '<',
                onError: '<'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {.....}
```

tnx !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know 'directory' is? To send data between the main process and renderer process in Electron then you can use [IPC](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md).